# Vertical Nav bar separates from header when I scroll

Tags: html, css, navbar, styling

I'm creating a vertical nav bar that I want fixed on the left hand side and for the container to take up the entire height of the window. It's fine and dandy until I scroll down. The pictures below will explain everything.

Looks fine here

[image]

Looks not fine here

[image]

HTML

```html
<h1>Blazing Bevy</h1>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <NavLink href="/">Play</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <NavLink href="/About">About</NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```css
nav {
    border-right: 10px solid #626262;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    width: 6.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scroll with header and nav(sidenav) then you should fixed header too and if you want scroll with only sidenav then you should go with sticky like this

```
 nav {
border-right: 10px solid #626262;
height: 100vh;
position: sticky;
width: 6.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Using a fixed header and a fixed nav ended up solving my issue. Granted that did make it a bit trickier to place elements in relation to those but hey, i worked. I'm not trying to be a CSS wiz I just want my website up haha.

https://bevy-blazor-webapp.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it with CSS grid: Make the `body` a grid container, and divide it into a top section, a side section, and a main section, and give the main section an `overflow-y` of `scroll`.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 20fr;
}

body > * {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0.5em solid black;
  background: gray;
}

header {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

main {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Blazing Bevy</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/">Play</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/About">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
</main>
```